# Write custom grid layouts with extbase/fluid but without any extension like gridelements

Tags: layout, grid, typo3, frontend, backend

I look for a tutorial, help or an example that tells me what I have to do to write a grid element like 2-colums in basic typo3 (v9) with fluid but no other extension like gridelements, DCE, Templa Voila, etc. I want the same gridelements can do but I dont want to be depended to this extention and move it in my own site extention.

I tried the same with normal content elements (CE) like here:
https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-fluid-styled-content/9.5/en-us/AddingYourOwnContentElements/Index.html

But how can I nest a CE in a CE? And how can I do this by drag&drop in the backend?

Comment: How much flexibility do you need? If it's always 2 columns you need, maybe you can you do what you want with backend layouts? https://usetypo3.com/backend-layouts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would at least have to add the necessary backend rendering methods to a draw item hook, that will modify the preview of the container element.

So basically you would have to rewrite everything that DCE, Flux, Gridelements or other similar extensions already do.

Which brings us to the question, why you want to avoid those extensions, since especially those three are well known, widely spread, well supported and available for currently supported TYPO3 versions.

Comment: I had many problems with extensions in the past. First Templa Voila stops maintaining. Then from Typo3 7 to 9 Mask and Gridelements do not work anymore as expected. I have to start once more from the beginning and hoped there is a way WITHOUT extensions.

Comment: Mask with Mask_export is full core way. However gridelements is something different

Comment: Mask does not provide any grid layouts, just nested content elements based on IRRE. So basically it's a kick starter for TCA based elements, nothing more, nothing less.

Gridelements provides the grids you have been asking for and it has been working the same way and backwards compatible without breaking changes for several different CMS versions from 4 up to 9.

So if you have got problems with your Gridelements while going from CMS 7 to 9, maybe you should ask for help instead of starting from the beginning. You can do that here or in the Gridelements channel on the official TYPO3 slack.

Comment: Hi Jo! Ok, I understand there is no way around gridelements ;) I found a tutorial to move everything in an own extention (found it onlwa in german): http://www.typo3-probleme.de/2017/04/07/typo3-8-7-x-gridelements-typoscript-tca-und-templates-auslagern-1985/. It does not work and I can not find anything in your documentation. Do you know a source for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The page module doesn't support nesting

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest CEs in a CE. On database level this would mean that you have to make a tt_content record a subrecord of a parent tt_content record. You run into several problems, basically the multilanguage support will be broken and the shortcut element does not function as you will expect it to. That is why the extensions "gridelements" and "mask" exist.

I integrated the gridelements configuration into my sitepackage. So I do not need to bother anymore with it.

Just for your info:
There is now an initiative that works on integrating this functionality into the core (Structured Content Initiative, https://typo3.org/article/a-structured-content-initiative/). Stay tuned to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about providing Gridelements via external files, since it's based on `TSconfig`, `TypoScript` and `Fluid`. That's why there is not that much about it in the documentation, since it's the same thing you would do with any other kind of sitepackage. The TSconfig and TypoScript parameters are already explained there, while the Fluid would be up to you anyway.

To have a kind of kickstarter just take any extensions providing Gridelements layouts as an example. A very popular one would be bootstrap_grids, which can be found in the TER or here: https://github.com/laxap/bootstrap_grids

You don't necessarily need the flexform controller of that extension, but the `Configuration` and `Resources` folders, show you how to configure stuff and you can see how that is included via ext_localconf.php

There are even comments i.e. in the TSconfig files to explain what is possible there and how to handle i.e. mixed environments with record and file based setups. Although it would be recommended to go for files.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try!

Comment: Ok, got it working. If you understand it gridelements is a nice one :) There is only one point left: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/85183 Is this possible today? I can not find anything on the net. It would give me the oportunity to use gridelements for everything.

Comment: That's not yet implemented but might be in the next versions for CMS 9, 8 and 7.